# How do I correctly expose a custom Vector class derived from Eigen::Matrix in pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, eigen, pybind11

I am trying to create bindings to my custom vector-class `Vec3` which inherits from the fixed-size matrix class `Eigen::Vector3d`, has a copy-constructor and implements some additional methods. Everything works fine until I try to call the derived class' method, where I get an `incompatible function arguments` error, even though the methods don't take any arguments.

#### Minimal Reproducible example

bindings.cpp:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Core>

#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/eigen.h"

namespace py = pybind11;

class Vec3 : public Eigen::Vector3d {
 public:
  Vec3() : Eigen::Vector3d() {}
  Vec3(const Eigen::Vector3d& v) : Eigen::Vector3d(v) {}
  Vec3(int rows, int cols) : Vec3() {}  // This constructor is needed for a problem-unrelated reason
  int f() { return 123; }  // I want to call this dummy method in python
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(Minimal, m) {
  py::class_<Vec3>(m, "Vec3")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def(py::init<const Eigen::Vector3d&>())
    .def("f", &Vec3::f);
}
```

I am using pybind11 version 2.4.3. CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Minimal)
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

set(PYBIND11_CPP_STANDARD -std=c++17)
set(PYBIND11_PYTHON_VERSION 3.6)
add_subdirectory(pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(Minimal "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/bindings.cpp")
    
target_link_libraries(Minimal PRIVATE Eigen3::Eigen)
```

After compiling, this is the outcome:

```sh
$ python3 -c "from Minimal import Vec3; v = Vec3([0, 0, 0]); print(v.f());"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: numpy.ndarray[float64[3, 1]]) -> int

Invoked with: <Minimal.Vec3 object at 0x7f4561fd35a8>
```

#### What else I've tried

I suspected that pybind11 might not have realized that `Vec3` inherits from `Eigen::Vector3d`, so I explicitly instructed it so.

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(Minimal, m) {
  py::class_<Eigen::Vector3d>(m, "Vector3d");
  py::class_<Vec3, Eigen::Vector3d>(m, "Vec3")
    .def(py::init<>())
    .def(py::init<const Eigen::Vector3d&>())
    .def("f", &Vec3::f);

  // These two lines also didn't help
  // py::implicitly_convertible<Eigen::Vector3d, Vec3>();
  // py::implicitly_convertible<Vec3, Eigen::Vector3d>();
}
```

Unfortunately I was met with the same error as above. Can someone help me?

Comment: if you try to remove base class Eigen::Matrix from Vec3 and make Vec3 standalone, does it works then ?

Comment: It does work, but I am required to inherit from `Eigen::Matrix` due to company constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove or comment out: #include "pybind11/eigen.h"

Comment: This did solve my original question, but I had to update it. The class still has to interface tightly with Eigen::Matrix (I want to be able to initialize it by passing a vector, and there are custom methods that shall return Eigen objects), so I think I can't go without `python11/eigen.h`. Without the eigen header, the copy-constructor fails with:
`incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported: [...] Minimal.Vec3(arg0: Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1, 0, 3, 1>)`